# Casio calculator key press event in MicroPython

Tags: event-handling, calculator, keypress, micropython

Is there a way to use a Casio calculator, like 'fx-CG50', that accepts python to listen to pressed keys?

Currently the only way to use user input that I found was the console input. Is there another way?
Casio does not provide any documentation at all. The used libraries like 'casioplot' do not help handling input.

Maybe there is a native way in MicroPython I don't know of, since it runs on the chip itself.